# Apache Storm: throttling spout based on configuration

Tags: apache-storm

My topology reads from Kafka and makes a HTTP call to an external system. The ingestion rate in Kafka is about 200 messages per second. The external system only supports 20 HTTP calls per second. How can i introduce throttling so that the bolt that makes HTTP calls processes only 20 messages per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `topology.max.spout.pending` setting to throttle the spout based on how many tuples are in flight in the topology. The setting is per spout instance, so if you have e.g. 10 spout executors and you set max 100 tuples, you will get a max of 1000 tuples in the topology.

You can use the `resetTimeout` method on the `OutputCollector` to keep tuples you want to postpone from failing due to timeout.

This being said, you probably need to batch up your messages into larger bundles. If you can only process 20 messages per second, and you have an input of 200 per second, you will start falling behind and never catch up.

Comment: I get requests in bursts which i have to relay at 20 messages per second. Hence, catching up is not a problem. How can I make sure bolts are not processing more messages per second than the configured threshold?

Comment: You can write a throttling bolt. Use the topology.max.spout.pending to stop the spout from emitting more than some number of tuples at a time. The throttling bolt should receive the emitted tuples, and only let e.g. 20 pass per second. You can use the resetTimeout method to keep the tuples from timing out while the throttling bolt is holding on to them. You can use tick tuples to keep time.

Another option is that you wrap the KafkaSpout in your own spout implementation, and only allow it to emit 20 tuples per second. That might be simpler.